# Unable to publish private android app in google private play store

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying to upload a private app APK through the google admin console.

When I attempt to upload it, showing "Can't publish app. Try again in a few minutes."

Please help....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is related to the Google Play Store which is hardly related to programming. Plus, you have given no details whatsoever which makes resolving this nearly impossible.

Comment: Just a suggestion before this question is closed, Make sure you are using a signed APK. Google play will normally show what the problem is. It is also possible that it is indeed a temporary issue and you should try again after a few minutes.

Comment: Yes its signed apk , Already uploaded past two version before six month without issue. This app updated version. All are fine but when i trying to upload got this error message.

Comment: Have you tried waiting a few minutes?  It sounds like a transient issue.

Comment: I have tried multiple times over the past 24 hrs.